# How to save attachments and rename it

Tags: vba, outlook

I am having an issue getting my code to work.  This is my first time running a VBA script.  I have a large amount of emails coming in from a fax machine and I want to be able to download the attachments, rename the file to the subject line and then store them on my computer.

My first attempt, I tried to just write a macro so that I could manually do it but after doing some research, I was under the impression that I wanted to make rules work.

This is my first attempt at VBA so I'm not even sure I am running the macro or rule script correctly but I have a feeling I am just missing something in the code.  Any thoughts?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDiskRule(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oldName

    Dim file As String
    Dim DateFormat As String
    Dim newName As String

    Dim enviro As String
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    saveFolder = enviro & "\" & "\destinationfolder\"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
     file = saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
     objAtt.SaveAsFile file

     Set oldName = fso.GetFile(file)
     newName = itm.Subject
     oldName.Name = newName

     Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next

     Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` This line is kinda suppressing all errors. Remove it and try your running the code again so you can properly diagnose your code.

Comment: Removing For Each throws an error.  I removed On Error Resume Next and the same thing happens, I run the script and it runs and does nothing with no errors.

Comment: Please trace the script by setting a breakpoint (F9 key) and then repeatedly pressing F8 key and tell us how it behaves. During that time, you can hover mouse pointer above the variables to inspect their content.

Comment: your variable saveFolder is combining the environment profile and path so it is most likely c:\users\<userProfile>\C:destination.  The you do file = saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
so it would be c:\users\<userProfile>\C:destination<attachmentName>  you still need a path separator so saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName.  That is after you fix the saveFolder path

Comment: Ok, I believe I've fixed the file path.  I now get the correct value in saveFolder but stepping through the program with F8 gets hung up with a runtime error 434 at 'file = saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName'.  I believe objAtt.DisplayName is empty and never gets a value but I'm not sure.

Comment: So I got this code to work but it is not renaming it as the subject line unfortunately.  Almost working.  I'll edit the above code to reflect what I have so far.

Comment: It now works thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple rule script

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim SaveFolder As String

    SaveFolder = "c:\temp\"

    For Each olAttachment In olItem.Attachments
        olAttachment.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & "\" & olAttachment.DisplayName
        Set olAttachment = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

[Environ Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fx287h4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

The Environ function lets you get the Windows environment variables for the computer your code is currently running on, Like `user name` or the name of the `temporary folder`

Examples

*user's profile folder example is*

```
Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Temp\"
result
Windows Vista/7/8:  C:\Users\Omar\
Windows XP:         C:\Documents and Settings\Omar\
```

*"All Users" or "Common" profile folder*

```
Environ("ALLUSERSPROFILE")
```

*Temporary folder example is*

```
Environ("TEMP") (or Environ("TMP") - is the same)
result: C:\Users\omar\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work which means that it is definitely my code and not running the rule incorrectly so that is a start.  Your code saves the file but does not rename it so I am currently working on that.  I tried a few quick modifications to no avail so Ill keep trying.

Comment: So I was able to get my code to do the exact same thing that your code does and I modified the original code up top to reflect what I now have.  It still will not make the new file name the subject line of the email.

Comment: No worries man.  I actually got it to work.  The code is fine I just had to add the .pdf extension to the filename and it now works.  Thanks for your help!