# How can I copy data from one workbook and create another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to know how I can copy data from one workbook and paste it into another workbook. Note - 'Another workbook' contains a specific format in which data should be pasted and the first workbook is humongous source of data, so I should be able to go to a specific tab, unhide hidden columns, apply date filters, remove the data not needed and then paste the remaining fields and data in second workbook.

[image: Review dates Tab]

[image: Specified format]

```
Option Explicit

Sub EventsForTomorrow()
'
' EventsForTomorrow Macro
' This macro will fetchevent scheduled for tomorrow data from AIX workbook
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\agoel5\Desktop\2015 AIX Integrated Workbook and Schedule.xlsb"
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Review_Dates").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1 _
        :=xlFilterTomorrow, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    Columns("A:BD").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("B:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:L").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("J:J").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    Columns("J:AL").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("Review_Dates[[#Headers],[Planned Date]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("A3:I14181").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\agoel5\Desktop\Events for tomorrow format.xlsx"
    Range("B7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("G10").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how it's not working?  Either that or  spell out what you want to do.  I can see what this code is doing, but I'm not exactly sure what you want it to do.  Maybe a before and desired after sample?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Hambone! First of all this code has become system specific/user specific (please see the code where i am asking the code to open a workbook) ,if i share this macro with my team that link becomes orphan ,resulting in a code crash

Comment: if the problem is with link, then you should use `Environ("USERPROFILE")` [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820485/not-able-to-get-my-vba-code-to-work-outlook-2010/31820964#31820964)  `sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Events for tomorrow format.xlsx`

Comment: (USERPROFILE)? shall i enter the name of user here?

Comment: You enter the code literally as posted by @Om3r

Comment: i did that but the code crashes again - Compile Error: Syntax Error

Comment: Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\2015 AIX Integrated Workbook and Schedule.xlsb"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have some useful answers in the comments above, but here are a few extra tips:
You don't need to "select" objects in order to use them in VBA. The lines where you have:

```
Columns("B:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

... can simply be written as:

```
Columns("B:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Also you don't need *any* of the ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn lines. These will typically be added into your code by the macro recorder, because it records every single change you make. The macro recorder is a great way to start learning VBA, but the next step you'll take is to realise that half the lines generated are unnecessary :)

Another thing you might like to do is to add the following at the beginning and end of your code:

```
Application.Screenupdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ... your code here
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Screenupdating = True
```

Without these lines, you may notice the screen flickering as it visually displays all the steps to the user; and you may have some speed issues due to the repeated recalculation of formulæ on your sheet as cells are modified. The lines above suspend these activities from taking place at the beginning of your code, then reinstate them at the end.